# How to save app data after restart of an app - flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, save

I was wondering how to make my app save data after restart? (The user can delete task and add new task to list, as well as check the box that the task is done. I want the app to save this data so when the user exists the app it will display all the tasks that he left the app with)

I was reading on google for few hours now, I got to
[1]: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files
This link as someone recommended on a similar post. But after reading it through I am a bit confused about where to start with my app.

Including some of my code and if you could help me I would really appreciate it as after hours of reading and watching tutorials I am still quite unsure where to start or which way of doing this is best.

My main.dart is this

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          TaskData(), //changing builder: to create: fixed the errors i been having
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: TasksScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
    class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
      List<Task> _tasks = [
        Task(name: "Sample task 1"),
        Task(name: "Sample task 2"),
        Task(name: "Sample task 3"),
      ];
    
      UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
        return UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
      }
    
      int get taskCount {
        return _tasks.length;
      }
void addTask(String newTaskTitle) {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskTitle);
    _tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateTask(Task task) {
    task.toggleDone();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteTask(Task task) {
    _tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The basic method is using the device local storage.

1 - Add the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in your pubspec.yaml
2 - Create a class  to write and read data :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class StoreData {

  StoreData._privateConstructor();
 
  static final StoreData instance = StoreData._privateConstructor();

  Future<void> saveString(String key, String value) async {
    
    try{
      SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final encodedValue = base64.encode(utf8.encode(value));

      pref.setString(key, encodedValue);
    } catch (e){
      print('saveString ${e.toString()}');
    }
    
  }

  
  Future<String> getString(String key) async {
    
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = pref.getString(key) == null ? '' : pref.getString(key);

    if (value.length > 0) {
      final decodedValue = utf8.decode(base64.decode(value));  
      return decodedValue.toString();
    }
    
    return '';
  }
  
  Future<bool> remove(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.remove(key);
  }

}
```

3 Use :

Save Data:

```
StoreData.instance.saveString('name', 'sergio');
```

Retrieve Data:

```
final String storedName = await StoreData.instance.getString('name');
print('The name is $storedName');
```

We have many other methods, like use a SQlite, NoSql or a Database in back-end, but the local storage is the most basic case

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply.  Question, where do I implement this code in the main.dart, in my task_data where I have the list, or do I create completely new dart file ?

Comment: Or where do i put the save data, and retrieve data code ? (Not sure how to use the code)

Comment: My suggest...Implement in a new Class (new dart file) and call on you need.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand this code at all :| Im completely new to this and I don't know what it all means so I have no idea how and where to implement/how to edit :| I think I need to google again or research or just forget about saving data and change my app a little

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a database or a document based data storage. You can store data in a local sqlite db, using `sqflite` plugin. Or you can store in a JSON asset file.

You can also use a server or cloud service. Firebase is pretty well integrated with flutter, but AWS and Azure are also great.

You can write the data in a text file in the asset, but that would very complicated.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I can't figure it out how to implement the JSON or SQLITE to my code, I read couple example found online but it just gives me headache. I found some firebase tutorials, but they usually include registration and login pages, and all I want is just to save the data, what do you think will be the simplest solution :?

Comment: You can check the docs on `sqflite` package: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Comment: You can also add a JSON file in your assets folder and add the asset location to your pubspec.yaml